# How do you append page context to URL String in JSP that is not in a DOM tag

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, tomcat7

I am using the page context to reference certain resources on my Tomcat web server. For instance I use it to get an image as follows:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading">
```

When I try to do the same thing for a src that is just string, and not inside of a document tag like above,  I get an error. How can I add context to a plain String? Or is this not allowed.

```
//This does not work and gives me syntax errors

if(response.validation === "success")
        window.location.href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}+"dashboard.jsp";
    else{
        $("#notification").append("<td><center>You have entered an incorrect username or password</center></td>");
    }
    });

//This works but I don't want to do it this way
  if(response.validation === "success")
        window.location.href="http://69.164.xx.xx:8080/MySite/dashboard.jsp";
    else{
        $("#notification").append("<td><center>You have entered an incorrect username or password</center></td>");
    }
  });

//Edit: Rendered Page after using first option

if(response.validation === "success")
        window.location.href=/RiverBoat+"dashboard.jsp";
    else{
        $("#notification").append("<td><center>You have entered an incorrect username or password</center></td>");
    }
  });
```

Comment: "Syntax error on token delete else", "Missing semicolon"

Comment: What does the rendered javascript look like when you use the first option?

Comment: See edits for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSP

```
window.location.href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}+"dashboard.jsp";
```

renders to

```
window.location.href=/RiverBoat+"dashboard.jsp";
```

which is invalid javascript and you get a syntax error.

You'd want it to be rendered to

```
window.location.href="/RiverBoat"+"dashboard.jsp"; // or rather `"/RiverBoat" + "/dashb..."
```

so just add the quotes

```
window.location.href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"+"dashboard.jsp";
```

As stated in the code comment above, you probably want `"/dashboard.jsp"`.